# Shifting Bits from a NamedPipeClientStream

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I am currently trying to write a bit synchronous serial protocol that reads data through a NamedPipeClientStream. This data then needs to be continuously monitored for sync characters (Hex 22) that may or may not be on the byte boundaries  and shift the data accordingly to ensure that the other data being received is in Frame.

I have prototyped several scenarios including a bit array and using a BitStream object designed by a person who posted to this site all of which seem cumbersome and most likely very inefficient.

The data being sent will continue to come in after the sync characters have been found so i must continue to add the incoming data to the end of the bit stream that was shifted.

Comment: Show the essence of what you prototyped (code) and why you think the approach is poor.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly bad design. Determining the byte boundries of a bit stream is something that should be done as soon as the bits are being read from the input device. Certainly not after pushing them through a named pipe. Sorry, but that sounds crazy.

Comment: Rennie : I don't think you are an engineer.  I've designed hardware that does exactly what John is suggesting.  John is using a very common transmission scheme and is trying to decode the received data in software instead of hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("filename");
            UInt16 chr = (UInt16)reader.Read();
            UInt16 word = 0;
            int shift = -1;

            while (shift == -1)
            {
                word = (UInt16)((UInt16)(word << 8) | chr);
                shift = TestSync(chr, word);
            }
            while ((chr = (UInt16)reader.Read()) >= 0)
            {
                word = (UInt16)((UInt16)(word << 8) | chr);
                byte newChar = (byte)((word >> shift) & 0xff);

            }


        }
        static int TestSync(UInt16 chr, UInt16 word)
        {
            int results = -1;


            if((UInt16)(word & 0xff) == 0x11) return 0;
            if((UInt16)(word & 0xff) == 0x22) return 1; 
            if((UInt16)(word & 0xff) == 0x44) return 2;
            if((UInt16)(word & 0xff) == 0x88) return 3;
            if((UInt16)(word & 0x1fe) == 0x110) return 4;
            if((UInt16)(word & 0x3fc) == 0x220) return 5;
            if((UInt16)(word & 0x7f8) == 0x440) return 6;
            if ((UInt16)(word & 0xff0) == 0x880) return 7;

            return results;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: You're not indicating how your "while (true)" gets terminated for either success or failure.

Comment: It is just an algorithm.  Came up with a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks jdweng will try this this week it gives me a starting point to build off of will let you know how it turns out